# How can I show the device's current location with other interested location in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

Basically I am developing an app which can show both the users' current location and their interested locations on the map, I know there are MyLocationOverlay and ItemizedOverlay, but seems they can only show either current location or interested location.

Thank you so much

Comment: What do you mean by other interested locations? You can put more than 1000 overlay items over the MapView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this tutorial and learned a lot http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-mall-finder-app-mapview-location/